# Flask Post method unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, flask, post

I want to perform two actions on one route:

1. I want to show only information from table **jobs** for a specific
   ID that was provided on the previous page.
2. After clicking the Apply button I want to insert a new record to the
   table **dashboard**.

Terminal shows me that:
`dashboard_add() got an unexpected argument 'job_id'`

Python code:

```python
@app.route('/jobs/<job_id>') 
def job_detailed_view(job_id):
     detailed_view = fetch_specific(job_id)
     return render_template('detailed-view.html', job=detailed_view)

def fetch_specific(job_id):
     query = """
             SELECT * FROM jobs
             WHERE job_id = %(job_id)s
             """
     return execute_select(query, {'job_id': job_id}, False)

@app.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=['POST'])
def dashboard_add():
     apply_date = datetime.now()
     apply_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
     applied_job_id = int(request.form.get('add_item_index', 0))
     apply_job(applied_job_id, apply_date)
     return redirect('home')

def apply_job(job_id, apply_date):
     execute_insert ("""
             INSERT INTO dashboard (job_id, apply_date)
              VALUES
             (%(job_id)s, %(apply_date)s)
             """, {'job_id': job_id, 'apply_date': apply_date})
```

Also HTML looks like this:

First code re-directs to the page with specific id and the second should pass the data to POST method.

```html
<div class="job-title">
  <a href="{{ "/jobs/" + (job['job_id']|string) }}">{{job['job_title']}}</a>
</div>

<form method="post" action="{{ "/jobs/" + (job['job_id']|string)}}">

  <input type="hidden" name="add_item_index" value="3">

  <button class="apply" type="submit" name="add_item">
  Apply
  </button>

</form>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I created one route with two different functions to avoid performing two actions in one route.

Comment: *"I created one route with two different functions to avoid performing two actions in one route."* -- Flask's documentation is littered with one route, one function examples. Almost all of them have `if request.method == 'POST':` somewhere near the top. [Here's one such example.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tutorial/views/#login)

Answer (score 0):

This is the url route definition for the `job_detailed_view()` view function:

```
@app.route('/jobs/<job_id>')
```

And this is the url route definition for the `dasboard_add()` view function:

```
@app.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=['POST'])
```

Those urls are identical.  Don't do that.  Use different urls.

Flask will NOT recognize that it should use the first view function for GET requests and the second function for POST requests, as you seem to expect.

Comment: Or use the one URL and only one route function and check for `GET` or `POST` and call helper functions from the route function.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in addition to [John Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097424/1241334), which answers your question.

Another approach is to check if the request method is `GET` or `POST` and call helper functions accordingly, instead of using different URLs, as in the example below.

Note that I don't have a way to test this code, so there may be some trivial errors. Also, you might not need the first `@app.route('/jobs/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))`.

```python
@app.route('/jobs/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@app.route('/jobs/<job_id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def jobs_job_id(job_id=None):
    job_id = request.form.get('add_item_index', job_id)
    
    # redirect if GET w/ no job_id, or POST w/ no add_item_index
    if job_id is None:
        return redirect('home')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return dashboard_add(int(job_id))
    
    return job_detailed_view(job_id)

def job_detailed_view(job_id):
    detailed_view = fetch_specific(job_id)
    return render_template('detailed-view.html', job=detailed_view)

def fetch_specific(job_id):
    query = """
            SELECT * FROM jobs
            WHERE job_id = %(job_id)s
            """
    return execute_select(query, {'job_id': job_id}, False)

def dashboard_add(job_id):
    apply_job(job_id, datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
    return redirect('home')

def apply_job(job_id, apply_date):
    query = """
            INSERT INTO dashboard (job_id, apply_date)
            VALUES
            (%(job_id)s, %(apply_date)s)
            """
    execute_insert(query , {'job_id': job_id, 'apply_date': apply_date})
```